# Terraform using output from another module doesnt work due to: Can't access attributes on a list of objects

Tags: terraform

I am trying to do something straightforward in terraform, referencing the output of one module to use in a different module.

I am doing things exactly as all expected answers on StackOverflow and terraform documentation but I am still facing issues.

This is my folder structure:

```
 -multicloud
     |_1-resource-groups.tf
     |_2-storage.tf
     |_variables.tf
     |_outputs.tf
 -modules
     |_azure
         |_resource-groups
                 |_main.tf
                 |_outputs.tf
                 |_variables.tf
         |_storage-account
                 |_main.tf
                 |_outputs.tf
                 |_variables.tf
```

The content of the ***outputs.tf*** in the resource-group module are:

```
output "resource-group-name" {
  description = "The name for the resource-group that will be created"
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.smc-resource-group.name
}
output "resource-group-id" {
  description = "The id for the resource-group that will be created"
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.smc-resource-group.id
}
```

The content of the ***outputs.tf*** in the multicloud root folder are:

```
## General
output "cloud-provider" {
  description = "The name for the cloud-provider"
  value       = var.cloud
}

output "resource-group" {
  description = "The name for the resource-group that will be created"
  value       = module.azure-resource-group
}
```

And The content of the ***storage.tf*** in the multicloud folder(which is my root folder) are:

```
module "azure-storage-account" {
  count                       = var.cloud == "azure" ? 1 : 0
  depends_on                  = [module.azure-resource-group]
  source                      = "../../modules/azure/storage-account"
  resource_group_name         = module.azure-resource-group.resource-group-name
  storage_account_name        = "${var.storage_account_name}${var.environment}"
  location                    = var.location
  tags                        = var.tags
}
```

The error I get when running terraform is attached below:

```
     Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on 2-storage.tf line 6, in module "azure-storage-account":
│    6:   resource_group_name         = module.azure-resource-group.resource-group-name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.azure-resource-group is a list of object
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "resource-group-name" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
```

The output for the resource group is indeed a list, which is strange because I would expect that to be a string, My guess is it's turning into a list because this is a module output and not a simple resource output.
[image]

anyway, I tried tons of ways to make it work but none worked, except taking the value from the backend state file which is not something I want to do and also seems like overhead for this basic need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code in the question should not result in such an output.

Comment: The error is about `module.azure-resource-group` module yet you haven't showed how you create it. Also please do not post errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: I posted the error on both the code block and screenshot.

Comment: @Marcin the error is on the module.azure-storage-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After breaking my module and .tf files into small pieces,
I finally found the issue.

It turns out that once a resource uses count, any reference to its name needs to be indexed.

so in order to return a single response in this output value you need to decide what the value ought to be([This was very helpful for me to understand](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-outputs-with-count-index/32555)).

Terraform has a built-in function one 371 to help deal with that situation in a concise way:

The expression above first uses the splat operator to transform the list of objects into a list of just storage-names values, which will also have either zero or one element depending on the resource count.

```
output "azure-storage-account" {
  description = "The name & id for the storage-account that will be created"
  value       = one(module.azure-storage-account[*].smc-storage-account-name)
}
```

So when calling the module and giving it an argument from a different module I would use:

```
module "azure-storage-container" {
  count                       = var.cloud == "azure" ? 1 : 0
  depends_on                  = [module.azure-storage-account]
  source                      = "../../modules/azure/storage-container"
  storage_account_name        = one(module.azure-storage-account[*].smc-storage-account-name)
  storage_container_name      = var.storage_container_name
  container_access_type       = var.container_access_type
}
```